# Advancing a SpriteKit physics simulation to a stable rest state

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm using SprikeKit's physics to simulate a fairly simple set of balls trapped in a containing circle. The initial world state is not stable, in that when the simulation starts, the balls will fall away from each other, bounce around, and eventually reach a rest state.

I'd like to advance the physics simulation to this rest state immediately, so the first thing a user sees is a stable world (until they perturb it themselves). Alas, I can't find any documentation on doing this. The only thing I can think of trying is setting the simulation speed to a stupidly high level for a short period of time, but this seems very hacky. Is there a method I've overlooked?

**Edit**: OK, I've experimented with accelerating the speed of the simulation. Unfortunately, this just produces simulation inaccuracies, such that no stable state is ever reached. Even with precise collision detection on, objects pass through each other, get stuck in each other, and jiggle around without converging to a solution. Even at a relatively modest 10x speedup, I can't get a stable solution.

Hiding the view whilst running the simulation at its natural speed will, of course, work. But I can't really use such a solution, as it creates an approximate 2 second delay in displaying the UI.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simulation step method you could run manually.

Like you said, setting the simulation speed might work. Otherwise you may just have to hide the view underneath a "blanket" sprite until the physics simulation has stabilized. Provided that it doesn't take longer than a few dozen frames or so.